# Use of operations in proof of vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

> **2.2**. For $\mathbf x,\mathbf y\in\Bbb R^n$ and $k\in\Bbb R$, define two operations as
>   $$\mathbf x\oplus\mathbf y=\mathbf x-\mathbf y,\quad\quad k\cdot\mathbf x=-k\mathbf x.$$
>   The operations on the right sides are the usual ones. Which of the rules in the definition of a vector space are satisfied for $(\Bbb R^n,\otimes,\cdot)$?

There are 10 conditions using addition and scalar multiplication to prove that a set is vector space. But I'm confused when new additions and multiplications are defined like, this problem.

For example, when I want to check $(a+b)x=ax+bx$, what must I check? $$(a+b)\cdot x = a\cdot x\oplus b\cdot x?$$
$$(a+b)\cdot x = a\cdot x+b\cdot x?$$
$$(a\oplus b)\cdot x = a\cdot x\oplus b\cdot x?$$
Likewise, I don't know exactly how to apply the new operation in some of the 10 conditions.

Comment: I don't see what's so difficult. *Replace* the operations "occasion by occasion".

Comment: Perfect. You're getting the hang of it. Now do this for the rest, and see which axioms are satisfied.

Comment: Thanks! From now, It is quite simple. All i have to do is Just changing all the symbol from usual to new one

Comment: Brilliant. That's all. People struggle with it initially, but then we are here to encourage them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is likely that your list of conditions essentially amounts of a list of equations that you need to check are satisfied. Write out that list with all of the $+$ signs replaced by $\oplus$ signs and all of the scalar multiplications replaced by $\cdot$. You are being asked to check which of the items in your new list are actually true statements, based on the definitions of $\oplus$ and $\cdot$ and the properties you know are true for $+$ and scalar multiplication.

Comment: Then to check '(a+b)x=ax+bx' in 10conditions, we have to check (a $\oplus$ b)•x = a•x $\oplus$ b•x ....right?

Comment: @nien: Yes, that's correct.